# Best practice for removing Mesh objects in ThreeJS?

Tags: vue.js, three.js

What are some common ways in ThreeJS to work with creating Meshes (consisting of Geometry and Materials) and then later deleting those objects?

My use case is to display lat/long points on a rotating 3D globe. Each point should be clickable and show further information. The points displayed should also be able to change based on data that is binded with Vue.

I currently use something like this but am running into memory leak issues:

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xdc143c,
});

var cone = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(radius, height, 8, 1, true),
  material
);
cone.position.y = height * 0.5;
cone.rotation.x = Math.PI;

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(sphereRadius, 16, 8),
  material
);

export default class Marker extends THREE.Object3D {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "Marker";
    this.add(cone, sphere);
  }

  destroy() {
    this.remove(cone, sphere);
  }
}
```

Are there libraries on top of Three that makes the management of Meshes/Materials/Geometry more simple to work with?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is create a function in some utils file, and any time I need to dispose of a mesh, I pass the mesh in as the function parameter:

```
    const removeMesh = (meshToRemove) => {

  meshToRemove.visible = false;
  scene.remove(meshToRemove);
  meshToRemove.geometry.dispose();
  meshToRemove.material.dispose();
  meshToRemove= undefined;

}
```